# Why my jQuery effect not performing like it state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 questions about my jQuery study today.

1. Why my jQuery code not have the animation effect as it should be? for example, .slideUp() and .slideDown(), my code shows something strange instead of slideUp animation.
2. I understand, the .hide() or .slideUp() function is only to HIDE the div box, not DELETE them, however, in my code, why the position of other div boxes changed after a DIV .hide()? Shouldn't it stay at their original position as the DIV box is still there, just HIDED?
3. How can I achieve to let other DIVs stay at the original position, when one DIV box has been hided?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#panel1').slideUp(1000).delay(1500).slideDown(1000);
});
```

```css
.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.panelTop {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panels">
  
  <div id="panel1" class="panel">
    <div class="panelTop">#panel1</div>
    <div class="panelBottom">content</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel2" class="panel">
    <div class="panelTop">#panel2</div>
    <div class="panelBottom">content</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel3" class="panel">
    <div class="panelTop">#panel3</div>
    <div class="panelBottom">content</div>
  </div>

  <div id="panel4" class="panel">
    <div class="panelTop">#panel4</div>
    <div class="panelBottom">content</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For your first question**

- > Why my jQuery code not have the animation effect as it should be? for
  >   example, .slideUp() and .slideDown(), my code shows something strange
  >   instead of slideUp animation.

The `.slideUp()` method animates the height of the matched elements. Means it **animates height so it reaches 0** (or, if set, to whatever the CSS min-height property is). See [here](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) for reference. That is exactly what is happening to your first box it is decreasing in height.

Afterwards the `display` style property is set to `none` to ensure that the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

**What display none does ?**

- > `display:none` means that the **tag** in question will not appear on the
  >   page **at all**

### Now for second and third question

- > I understand, the .hide() or .slideUp() function is only to HIDE the
  >   div box, not DELETE them, however, in my code, why the position of
  >   other div boxes changed after a DIV .hide()? Shouldn't it stay at
  >   their original position as the DIV box is still there, just HIDED?

---

- > How can I achieve to let other DIVs stay at the original position,
  >   when one DIV box has been hided?

The `.hide()` and `.slideUp()`function they both add `display:none` to your **tag** element. **Means they are gone now**

**Now what can you do to let them stay there, But hidden from view ?**

> You can use `visibility` or `opacity` property instead rather than using `display`
>   property.

For example: `visibility: hidden;` will just hide it from the view.

Will update your fiddle in order to demonstrate it in a while. Hope this will help you. Please feel free to ask if not clear. Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function(){ 

    $('#panel1').slideUp(1000).delay(500).slideDown(1000);

  }, 3000);
  
});
```

```css
.outer-div
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 1px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 90px;
}
.panel {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-left: 45px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
}
.panelTop {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="panels">
<div class="outer-div">
  <div id="panel1" class="panel">
    <div class="panelTop">#panel1</div>
    <div class="panelBottom">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer-div">
  <div id="panel2" class="panel">
    <div class="panelTop">#panel2</div>
    <div class="panelBottom">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer-div">
  <div id="panel3" class="panel">
    <div class="panelTop">#panel3</div>
    <div class="panelBottom">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer-div">
  <div id="panel4" class="panel">
    <div class="panelTop">#panel4</div>
    <div class="panelBottom">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Amkhan, thank you for your comprehensive answer, that solved most of my questions, just one more query, how can I achieve the slideUp()animated effect as it should be ? I have identical layout of my DIV box as the following link does, however , the link achieve the slideUp effect perfectly.

Comment: I have added a snippet into the Answer to demonstrate your `slideUp()` animation. Please see if this is of help to you

Comment: This is happening due to your css styles. I will update JsFiddle for you in a while in order to make it like the link you pasted above

Comment: Have updated the snippet for you. This is exactly as you want it. The link you shared they were using and `outer-div` to `panel`. You were missing that. Added it and made the inner div absolute to it. Hope the answer will be accepted as verified from your side now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display:flex` on `.panels`, that solves your first question.

For second question you should use `visibility` or `opacity`.
With current code you are removing it, although it is called `hide()` it is equivalent to CSS `display:none;` which doesn't keep space of element.

Although you actually don't need to set `visibility` in your case because sliding it up will hide element and down show.

Something like this:

```
$('#panel1').animate({
  top: -62 // 60 is height of element plus 2px of borders
}, 1000).delay(1500).animate({
  top: 0
}, 1000);
```

Also you have to change CSS a bit.
Add this to your CSS:

```
.panels {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

And from `.panel` remove `top: 20px;`

Full example is here https://jsfiddle.net/_jakob/cphptby3/1/

Comment: Hi Jakob, Great job! thank you for provide this demo for me. Another thing to learn is animate! However, I am keen to figure out how to let slideUp() do what it suppose to do by updating possible error in my code. Thank you again !

Comment: Well `slideUp()` is doing what it suppose to do. It sets element to `display:none` after animation is done like Amkhan explained to you. But if you still want to use that function then you'll have to do workaround with `opacity` or `visibility` as he also stated. You are welcome :)